# Can I use Django as backend framework for my blockchain website

Tags: django, blockchain

I am a beginner and wanted to make a blockchain project. I don't have any knowledge of blockchain as of now. I have a basic understanding of Django and have made a few projects. I was wondering can I make a blockchain website with react.js as the front-end and Django as the backend framework. Is Django viable for web3 or should I use Node.js (I don't know Node.js)? This is my final year of college and I have to make a decent project, so learning a new library like node.js will be very time-consuming.

Comment: of course you can, there is no need to learn node.js if you don't need it and don't have time for that. django is viable for web3.js.